# Add custom filed value in the_content in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add a custom filed value into a custom post content. That means into

```
 <?php the_content();>
```

I have used this code

```
   function custom_post_type_testimonial_default_content($content) {
       global $post;
       if ($post->post_type == 'testimonials') {
           $content .= '<br /><span class="violet">'. get_post_meta( $post->ID, "writer", true ).'</span>';
       }

}    
add_filter('the_content', 'custom_post_type_testimonial_default_content', 0);
```

But it is not working. I could not find the problem. Please tell me how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the `add_filter` method direct in your `functions.php`.

```
function custom_post_type_testimonial_default_content($content) {
       global $post;
       if ($post->post_type == 'testimonials') {
           $content .= '<br /><span class="violet">'. get_post_meta( $post->ID, "writer", true ).'</span>';
       }
       return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'custom_post_type_testimonial_default_content', 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call get_post_meta() for each custom field. Like if you two custom fields then you have to write the below code:

```
function custom_post_type_testimonial_default_content($content) {
   global $post;
   if ($post->post_type == 'testimonials') {
   $content .= '<br /><span class="violet">'. get_post_meta( $post->ID, "your_custom_field2_key", true ).'</span>';
$content .= '<br /><span class="violet">'. get_post_meta( $post->ID, "your_custom_field2_key", true ).'</span>';
   }
   return $content;
}
```